# Access the IBM AJAX Test Server over HTTPS?

Tags: https, ibm-rad

I'm using the [AJAX Test Server](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/topic/com.ibm.etools.webtoolscore.doc/topics/tcrtajaxtestserver.html) in Rational Application Developer. I'm posting a form to another host for authentication. That host takes a URL to redirect to after authentication. However, it insists on using HTTPS whenever it sends the 302 response. The low hanging fruit would be to just use HTTPS locally.

Looking at the launch configuration, the AJAX Test Server appears to be a [custom Apache HttpCore server](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/examples.html). I haven't spotted anything in the [configuration guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/topic/com.ibm.etools.webtoolscore.doc/topics/tconfigajaxtestserver.html).

Is there a way to access this test server via HTTPS?

*This is for demo and local development purposes; not production.*

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from working with WAS (WebSphere Application Server) in RAD, I'm pretty sure the answer would be yes. The server (at least with WAS) has both secure and "unsecure" ports.

What I have noticed is that when the server is built with the install (at least with the newer versions of the products 7.5+), the ports used are different per install. This is to help with not conflicting with other applications that may use those ports.

So https is probably fine. You just may have to use it over port 302 or some other port.

If there is no admin console for viewing your ports, you could always try the Window | Preferences option under your menu items. Sometimes IBM hides server config stuff in there.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood; the AJAX Test Server is not the WAS Java EE runtime - it is a lightweight container that serves static resources and has some built in proxying support.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand. I am not familiar with the AJAX Test Server (as I haven't used it yet), but was not sure of your familiarity with IBM products. So I tried to provide some help from the standpoint of where I figured you might have to look.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, but I think I've covered the usual suspects in RAD (server config/preferences/run config) and haven't been able to locate an admin console. The server only listens on a single port. I suspect that lack of HTTPS may just be a limitation of the implementation, but I thought I'd ask.